# Sibling + selector does't work in IE7 when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to select a sibling element using jQuery and it doesn't work in IE7.

Here is my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/y7AHz/6/  (click Run to see result)

```
var numberOfListItems = $("#txtInput + ul.ulContainer li").length;
$("#output").text(numberOfListItems);
```

In IE8, Firefox, Safari it works(# of list itmes comes out to 3).

Comment: jQuery uses sizzle.js. I am surprised that there is a difference between IE7 and modern browsers...

Comment: there is some problem this combination  of txtinput var numberOfListItems = $("#txtInput + ul.ulContainer li").length;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6279) with sizzle (the selector engine underneath jQuery) in IE6 and 7. Instead, use `.next()`, which is equivalent to the `+` or `next adjacent` selector, and `.find()`. It's more verbose, but it works in IE6+:

```
var numberOfListItems = $("#txtInput").next(".ulContainer").find("li").length;
```

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y7AHz/8/)

Comment: You can keep one part, just split out the li, ie. $("#txtInput + .ulContainer").find("li")

Answer (score 2):

This will also work in IE7:

```
var foo= $("#txtInput + ul.ulContainer");
var numberOfListItems = $('li', foo).length;

 $("#output").text(numberOfListItems);
```

Not sure which of the proposed fixes performs best, if it matters...

Answer (score 0):

try only this it works in ie7 also

```
var numberOfListItems = $("ul.ulContainer li").length;
```

Comment: This does not behave like the OP's selector.

Comment: @elusiv , i just found that there is some issue in that line of code and posted the same..

Comment: what is OP?? i always see lot of people using this.

Comment: Your selector is lacking the need of a `#txtInput` to be in front of the `ul`. You simply omitted that part. It does not do (exactly) what the OP wants.

Comment: OP is used as acronym for "Original Poster" (i.e. the creator of this question).